# How to call an operation from soap service using ngx soap?

Tags: angular, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am using Angular cli 8.3.0, using ngx-soap to call a soap service. I am getting the error 'TypeError: this.client.GetDocumentContent is not a function' from the code below.

```
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private soap: NgxSoapService,
    private messageService: MessageService) {  
      this.soap.createClient('http://<ip address>/test/iEDMSWSServ.svc?wsdl').then(client => {
        this.client = client;
        console.log('Created client!');
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });      
    }
```

```
(<any>this.client).GetDocumentContent(body).subscribe((res: ISoapMethodResponse) => console.log(res));
```

From wsdl..

```
<wsdl:message name="GetDocumentRequest">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDocumentRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetDocumentResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetDocumentResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="CreateDocumentRequest">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateDocumentRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="CreateDocumentResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateDocumentResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IWCFFacade">
<wsdl:operation name="GetDocumentContent">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IWCFFacade/GetDocumentContent" name="GetDocumentRequest" message="tns:GetDocumentRequest"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IWCFFacade/GetDocumentContentResponse" name="GetDocumentResponse" message="tns:GetDocumentResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="CreateDocument">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IWCFFacade/CreateDocument" name="CreateDocumentRequest" message="tns:CreateDocumentRequest"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IWCFFacade/CreateDocumentResponse" name="CreateDocumentResponse" message="tns:CreateDocumentResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="HttpBinding_IWCFFacade_IWCFFacade" type="tns:IWCFFacade">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetDocumentContent">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IWCFFacade/GetDocumentContent" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="GetDocumentRequest">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="GetDocumentResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="CreateDocument">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IWCFFacade/CreateDocument" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="CreateDocumentRequest">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="CreateDocumentResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

I am not sure if I am getting the right operation/call for the soap client. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can change your code as below:

```
this.client.call('GetDocumentContent', body).subscribe((res: ISoapMethodResponse) => console.log(res));
```

Reference: https://github.com/lula/ngx-soap/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I have tried using this.client.call(...... but received this error.
````Method GetDocumentContent not found````

Comment: Try chage `http://<ip address>/test/iEDMSWSServ.svc?wsdl'` to `'http://<ip address>/test/iEDMSWSServ.svc?singleWsdl'`

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed one thing in your code : the wsdl file must be downloaded and installed in your assets directory.

This file should not be directly called from an URL. This is stated in the description of the ngx-soap module (see references below) :
- https://gitlab.com/oldster189/ngx-soap
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-soap

Cordially,

Arcturien